# codeignither HMVC version 3.0.6 view not loading

Tags: codeigniter-3, hmvc

The follwing below is an controller for an template i am making in codeignither HMVC. I am trying to load this template module in my task modules but for some reason it wont load in the template modules but the data loads in my task controller.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class templates extends MX_Controller
{
    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */

    public function one_col($data)
    {
        $this->load->view('one_col',$data);
    }

    public function two_col($data)
    {
        $this->load->view('two_col',$data);
    }

    public function admin($data)
    {

         $this->load->view('admin', $data); 
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "Hello world";
    }
}
```

this code below is my task controller and it works fine when i run it in the link `http://localhost:81/hmvc/index.php/tasks` however when i try to run the template view "two_col" http://localhost:81/hmvc/index.php/templates/two_col

using this code in the template

```
<?php $this->load->view($module.'/'.$view_file); ?>
```

i get this error :
[image: picture error]

---

task module controller below

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class tasks extends MX_Controller
{
    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('mdl_tasks');
        $data['query'] = $this->mdl_tasks->get('priority');
        #$this->load->view('display', $data);
        $data['view_file'] = "display";
        $data['module'] = "tasks";
        echo Modules::run('templates/two_col', $data);
        #$this->load->module('templates');
        #$this->templates->two_col($data);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Those errors you are seeing are correct as you are calling the template methods with no $data, which the errors are stating. Missing Parameter $data in your "call" and it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo Modules::run('templates/two_col', $data);
        #$this->load->module('templates');
```

I'm pretty sure replacement these codes together will work.

Because php is an interpreted programming language. PHP loads every line one by one if deteced an error for ex. on 5Th line it doesnt compile the rest of lines. [More information for interpreted lang.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) and also in your code you implementing the lib function before loading lib

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Because php is an interpreted programming  language. PHP loads every line one by one if deteced an error for ex. on 5Th line it doesnt compile the rest of lines. [More information for interpreted lang.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language)

Comment: and also in your code you implementing the lib function before loading lib.

Comment: Ahmetcan, I think those comments should be added as an [edit] to your answer.